# Replace some string in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, replace

I have two address like:

```
first_address = 'Красноярский край, г Красноярск, пр-кт им газеты Красноярский Рабочий, 152г, квартира (офис) /1'
second_address = 'Красноярский край, г Красноярск, пр-кт им.газеты "Красноярский рабочий", 152г'
```

And I want to replace all text before **квартира (офис) /1**

My code looks like:

```
c = first_address.split(',')
v = second_address.split(',')
b = c[:len(v)]
b = v
n = c[len(v)::]
f = ''.join(str(b)) + ''.join(str(n))
```

I get output:

```
['Красноярский край', ' г Красноярск', ' пр-кт им.газеты "Красноярский рабочий"', ' 152г'][' квартира (офис) /1']
```

How can I easily make this?

Comment: Replace with what? What is the desired result? Is this always at the end of the string? Will `квартира (офис) /1` always be in the string? If so, you could just append that canned string to whatever you want to expand.

Comment: The second immediate assignment to `b` invalidates the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to take substrings from `second_address` until they run out, then use substrings from `first_address`. Here's a straightforward way to do it.

```py
first_subs = first_address.split(',')
second_subs = second_address.split(',')
[(f if s is None else s) 
 for (f, s) in zip(first_subs, 
                   second_subs + [None] * (len(first_subs) - len(second_subs)))]
```